# How can I install an X11 version of Emacs on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew, x11

I'd like to install an X11 version of Emacs on Catalina, but haven't found anything online that tells me how I might accomplish this.

The following worked for some previous versions of MacOS, including, I believe Mojave.

```
$ brew tap d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus
$ brew install /emacs-plus --with-x11
```

Unfortunately, at the moment, if you do this, you get only the "app" version of Emacs, not the X11 version.

The default Emacs recipe that comes with Homebrew does not currently support the "--with-x11" or "--with-x" option.

Is there another Emacs cask somewhere that supports X11?

P.S. I know that I could try to build Emacs directly from the Emacs sources myself, but from past experience, I am afraid that there be dragons along this path.

P.P.S. I seem to have gotten a working version of an X11 emacs installed by rsyncing the directory /usr/local/Cellar/emacs over from a Mac that is running Mojave. But clearly this is less than ideal, so I'm still looking for how I might accomplish this the "right" way.

Comment: Why? Apple has long moved on from X11.

Comment: @nega Because I personally have been religiously using X11 on Mac OS for the last 15 years, and I find it to be useful.

Comment: I can identify with that. I guess a more specific question would be why do you need an X11 version on macOS? What would lose by using a native GUI version of Emacs? I'm genuinely curious. When I moved to macOS (OS X) "full time" over 10 years ago, I personally chose to go "all in" and forego any non-native, and non-apple-styled apps to help get over the hump.

Comment: I remotely access a bunch of other computers from work and home (e.g., Linux servers, and my home Mac or work Mac), and xterm and Emacs with X11 let me do this is a way that is much more fluid than having to use remote desktop software. Also, if I used something like Aquamacs, it's not so easy to have multiple Emacs's open at once. Having everything in one Emacs does not suit me. It seems, however, that the Homebrew Emacs App let's me run mutliple Emacs's.

Comment: cool. if you're going to get your feet wet with `brew` provided emacs, my personal preference is the package provided by https://emacsformacosx.com/ (`brew cask install emacs`, or skip `brew` and just directly install the `.dmg` from there)

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite familiar with `brew`. I use it all the time, and have a non-X11 Emacs installed. It's the X11 emacs that is giving me indigestion this time around. (And I think last time around. I think I had to use fink to get an X11 Emacs.)

Comment: sorry. just recommending a specific version within homebrew.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

[I maintain my own brew formula for X11 emacs](https://github.com/julienchastang/homebrew-core/tree/x11emacs) that you may be able to use. I wrote about this in a blog entry [here](https://julienchastang.com/post/x11/).

Comment: Hi. Could you add a little detail for dummies? I don't know how to tell Homebrew to use an alternate version of homebrew-core.

Answer (score 1):

My last attempts to try to use homebrew to install X11 capable apps, especially Emacs, failed.  Once upon a time I had edited the homebrew recipe to make it compile a local version with X11 support, but I was giving up on maintaining that against the quickly moving target of homebrew and the mass migration of homebrew away from supporting X11.

So, really your best option is to build Emacs from source and install it.

(I've moved entirely away from homebrew as a result -- I only use pkgsrc now, and that gives one an easy way to reliably build Emacs with X11 support and manage all the dependencies, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll have to give pkgsrc a try! (Though it's sad to hear that Homebrew is moving away from supporting X11.)

Comment: Well, macOS is not the greatest platform overall for X11 anymore, sadly.  Next week I'll update the answer proper with a note about using binary packages built by Joyent in conjunction with manually built packages.  That makes things a little easier, and much faster.  In the mean time you can try pkgsrc with Joyent's binaries for a quick test, but note their emacs build is also not x11, thus the need to still build it from source.  With pkgsrc (and `pkgin`) you can mix 3rd party binaries and local-built packages and manage them together.

Comment: This it sad for me. I've been happily using X11 on MacOS for many a year!

Before Homebrew it required two different fink installations and a MacPorts installation to get all the software that I wanted installed. This was a bit of a chore, but it worked.

I look forward to your update. I think I'll probably hold off until then, since I have actual work to get done. Thanks muchly!

Comment: I see now by looking at my other Mac running Mojave, that the last time I installed Emacs, I had to use fink to get an Emac with X11. I suppose I can try that again too.

Comment: I stopped using Fink a very long time ago (before 10.6) -- I wonder if it is still a worse mess than Homebrew.

Comment: I'm not sure. Fink was never a joy to use, and it sometimes took some effort to get things to work. But last time I tried, I was able to get an X11 Emacs to build, and maybe a couple of other programs I wanted that I couldn't get to work under Homebrew.